# Pentaho : status 404 error on CentOS

Tags: java, tomcat, pentaho, centos6

I have to install Pentaho on a CentOS server, so I tried to install Pentaho on a my computer (Ubuntu 14.04) with success and afterwards, I tried to install it on CentOS 6 and Tomcat return me an 404 error on the url : "`http://localhost:8080/pentaho/`".

In order to explain what I did :

```
$> wget http://heanet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/pentaho/Business%20Intelligence%20Server/5.2/biserver-ce-5.2.0.0-209.zip
$> unzip biserver-ce-5.2.0.0-209.zip && cd biserver-ce
[...]
$> ./start-pentaho.sh
DEBUG: Using JAVA_HOME
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65.x86_64/jre
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65.x86_64/jre/bin/java
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The Pentaho BI Platform now contains a version checker that will notify you
when newer versions of the software are available. The version checker is enabled by default.
For information on what the version checker does, why it is beneficial, and how it works see:
http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/ServerDoc2x/Version+Checker
Press Enter to continue, or type cancel or Ctrl-C to prevent the server from starting.
You will only be prompted once with this question.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK]:

Using CATALINA_BASE:   /root/pentaho/biserver-ce/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /root/pentaho/biserver-ce/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /root/pentaho/biserver-ce/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65.x86_64/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /root/pentaho/biserver-ce/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar
$>

[I went to http://localhost:8080/ -> redirected to http://localhost:8080/pentaho/ with a status 404 error]
$> cd tomcat/logs/
$> cat catalina.out
[...]
07:22:25,425 ERROR [ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.h2.tools.Server' defined in file [/root/pentaho/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/GettingStartedDB-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Exception opening port "H2 TCP Server (tcp://localhost:9092)" (port may be in use), cause: "timeout" [90061-131]
[...]
$> cat pentaho.log
2014-10-14 07:22:25,425 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.h2.tools.Server' defined in file [/root/pentaho/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/GettingStartedDB-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Exception opening port "H2 TCP Server (tcp://localhost:9092)" (port may be in use), cause: "timeout" [90061-131]
```

When we check if the port 9092 is open or used, nmap says :

```
$> nmap -sT -O localhost    
Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-10-14 08:32 EDT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000012s latency).
rDNS record for 127.0.0.1: localhost.localdomain
Not shown: 993 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
3306/tcp open  mysql
8009/tcp open  ajp13
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
No exact OS matches for host (If you know what OS is running on it, see http://nmap.org/submit/ ).
TCP/IP fingerprint:
OS:SCAN(V=5.51%D=10/14%OT=22%CT=1%CU=41410%PV=N%DS=0%DC=L%G=Y%TM=543D17F8%P
OS:=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)SEQ(SP=104%GCD=1%ISR=10A%TI=Z%CI=Z%II=I%TS=A)OP
OS:S(O1=M400CST11NW7%O2=M400CST11NW7%O3=M400CNNT11NW7%O4=M400CST11NW7%O5=M4
OS:00CST11NW7%O6=M400CST11)WIN(W1=8000%W2=8000%W3=8000%W4=8000%W5=8000%W6=8
OS:000)ECN(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=8018%O=M400CNNSNW7%CC=Y%Q=)T1(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%S=O%
OS:A=S+%F=AS%RD=0%Q=)T2(R=N)T3(R=N)T4(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=A%A=Z%F=R%O=%RD=0
OS:%Q=)T5(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=Z%A=S+%F=AR%O=%RD=0%Q=)T6(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S
OS:=A%A=Z%F=R%O=%RD=0%Q=)T7(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=Z%A=S+%F=AR%O=%RD=0%Q=)U1(R
OS:=Y%DF=N%T=40%IPL=164%UN=0%RIPL=G%RID=G%RIPCK=G%RUCK=G%RUD=G)IE(R=Y%DFI=N
OS:%T=40%CD=S)

Network Distance: 0 hops

OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 12.21 seconds
$>
```

With the same archive and the same commands lines, I have no problem on Ubuntu 14.04.

Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 2):

In my case I fixed following: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pentaho-community/RRf97w782yQ

Change the default port for H2 in **GettingStartedDB.properties**

```
base.dir=../../pentaho-solutions/system/GettingStartedDB
tcp.port=9093
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it was resolved by editing /etc/hosts and providing an IP address of the machine hostname

vi /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost template
127.0.0.1 <name of the machine>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be H2 not being able to start or Pentaho not being able to connect to it on port 9092. Is there a firewall setting preventing you from accepting connections on that port? Try starting H2 separately and then try connecting to it. Read H2's logs, maybe there's something there that is more useful. Usually it starts out of the box.